# Can cocoapods-binary work with the Pods project generated by Flutter?

Tags: flutter, cocoapods

I've tried implemented it and `pod install` ran successfully. However, when building from Xcode I get many errors of files not being found like:

`FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' file not found`